# Ad hoc archive complaining about libxml (no such file or identity)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4, libxml2, ad-hoc-distribution

I ran my app in simulator and on my device and everything worked fine, but now I am trying to do an ad hoc distribution and it's complaining that libxml/parser.h (no such file or identity). What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your "Header Search Paths"

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```